# How single-label dns lookup requests are handled by systemd-resolved?

Tags: dns, systemd-networkd, systemd-resolved

I looked into the systemd-networkd and systemd-resolved:

- [systemd.network(5) on manpages.ubuntu.com](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man5/systemd.network.5.html)
- [systemd-resolved.service(8) on manpages.ubuntu.com](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html)

and I am confused by some words:

- systemd-resolved.service(8)

  > Single-label names are routed to all local interfaces capable of IP multicasting, using the LLMNR protocol.
  >   Lookups for a hostname ending in one of the per-interface domains are exclusively routed to the matching interfaces.
- systemd.network(5)

  > Both "search" and "routing-only" domains are used for routing of DNS queries: look-ups for host names ending in those domains (hence also single label names, if any "search domains" are listed), are routed to the DNS servers configured for this interface.

my question is: for hosts with a bunch of interfaces configured with "search domains" and LLMNR enabled, where will the single-label lookup requests go?

more details of my confusion:

- if an interface is configured with search domain "mydomain" and LLMNR
  disabled, will any single-label lookup request be routed into this
  interface?
- if an interface is configured with search domain    "mydomain" and
  LLMNR enabled and a lookup request for "xyz" comes in,    will "xyz"
  through LLMNR and "xyz.mydomain" throuth specified dns    server both
  happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue gets very long to explain. The short (imprecise) description is:

*where will the single-label lookup requests go?*

Single label? (not `localhost` et al.): Always to the LLMNR system.

Multi-label?: To the DNS servers of each interface. On failure (or if not configured), to the global DNS servers.

---

Yes, the general sequence goes as described in [systemd-resolved.service(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html) **BUT**:

> Routing of lookups may be influenced by configuring per-interface domain names. See [systemd.network(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man5/systemd.network.5.html) for details.

Sets the [systemd.network(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man5/systemd.network.5.html) as an additional resource for DNS resolution.

And, understand that [From RFC 4795](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4795):

> Since LLMNR only operates on the local link, it cannot be considered a substitute for DNS.

---

The sequence (simplified) is:

- The local, configured **hostname** is resolved to all locally configured IP addresses ordered by their scope, or — if none are configured — the IPv4 address 127.0.0.2 (which is on the local loopback) and the IPv6 address ::1 (which is the local host).
- The hostnames "localhost" and "localhost.localdomain" (and any hostname ending in ".localhost" or ".localhost.localdomain") are resolved to the IP addresses 127.0.0.1 and ::1.
- The hostname "_gateway" is resolved to …
- The mappings defined in `/etc/hosts` are included (forth and back).
- If [the name to search has no dots](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4821) (a name like `home.` has a dot) it is resolved by the LLMNR protocol.

  > LLMNR queries are sent to and received on port 5355.  [RFC 4795](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4795)
- Multi word (one dot or more) names for some domain suffixes (like ".local", see full list with `systemd-resolve --status`) are resolved via MulticastDNS protocol.
- Multi word names are checked against the `Domains=` list in [systemd.network(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man5/systemd.network.5.html) **per interface** and if matched, the list of DNS servers of **that** interface are used.
- Other multi-label names are routed to all local interfaces that have a DNS server configured, plus the globally configured DNS server if there is one.

---

#Edit

The title of your question reads:

> How single-label dns lookup requests are handled by systemd-resolved?

So, I centered my answer on `systemd-resolved` exclusively.

Now you ask:

1. If an interface is configured with search domain "mydomain" and LLMNR disabled, will any single-label lookup request be routed into this interface?
2. If an interface is configured with search domain "mydomain" and LLMNR enabled and a lookup request for "xyz" comes in, will "xyz" through LLMNR and "xyz.mydomain" throuth specified dns server both happen?

Those appear to be outside of `systemd-resolved` exclusively.

Let's try to analyze them:

- LLMNR disabled ?
  How? Might I ask?. By [disabling `systemd-resolved` itself](https://askubuntu.com/a/907249/772601) with something similar to `systemctl mask systemd-resolved`?

If `systemd-resolved` is disabled/stopped there is no [LLMNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-Local_Multicast_Name_Resolution) in use (most probably, unless you install Avahi, Apple bonjour or a similar program) But certainly, that is outside of `systemd-resolved` configuration.

In this case, we should ask: what happens when a name resolution fails? (as there is no server to answer it). That is [configured in `nsswitch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch) (file `/etc/nsswitch.conf`). The default configuration for Ubuntu (as Debian) contains this line:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

That [means](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=971693) (in nsswitch parlance):

1. Begin by checking the `/etc/hosts` file. If not found, continue.
2. Try `mdns4_minimal` ([Avahi et al.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking#Major_implementations)) which will attempt to resolve the name via multicast DNS only if it ends with .local. If it does but no such mDNS host is located, mdns4_minimal will return NOTFOUND. The default name service switch response to NOTFOUND would be to try the next listed service, but the [NOTFOUND=return] entry overrides that and stops the search with the name unresolved. If mdns4_minimal return UNAVAIL (not running) then go to dns.

[The plot thickens](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2017-June/290390.html) everybody wants to be [first on the list to resolve names](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5742) and everyone offers to do all resolutions by themselves.

3. The `dns` entry in `nsswitch` [actually calls `nss-resolve` first](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/nss-resolve.html) which replace nss-dns

   > nss-resolve is a plug-in module for the GNU Name Service Switch (NSS) functionality of the GNU C Library (glibc) enabling it to resolve host names via the systemd-resolved(8) local network name resolution service. It replaces the nss-dns plug-in module that traditionally resolves hostnames via DNS.

   Which will depend on the several `DOMAINS=` entries in general `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` and/or each interface via `/etc/systemd/network` files. That was explained above the **EDIT** entry.

   Understand that sytemd-resolved might query the dns servers by itself before the dns entry in nsswitch.
4. If not found yet (without a `[notfound=return]` entry) then try the DNS servers. This will happen more-or-less immediately if the name does not end in .local, or not at all if it does. If you remove the [NOTFOUND=return] entry, nsswitch would try to locate unresolved .local hosts via unicast DNS. This would generally be a bad thing , as it would send many such requests to Internet DNS servers that would never resolve them. Apparently, that happens a lot.
5. The final `myhostname` acts as a *last-resort* resolver for localhost, hostname, *.local and some other basic names.

If [`systemd-resolved` has a `LLMNR=no` set](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699632/how-to-completly-disable-llmnr) in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` the same list as above apply but `systemd-resolved` is still able to resolve `localhost` and to apply `DOMAINS=` settings (global or per interface).

Understand that *There's the LLMNR setting in systemd-resolved and there's also the per-link LLMNR setting in systemd-networkd.* [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025309/how-can-i-disable-llmnr-in-systemd-resolved).

#What does all that mean?
That it is very difficult to say with any certainty what will happen unless the configuration is very very specific. you will have to disable services and try (in your computer with your configuration) what will happen.

#Q1

> If an interface is configured with search domain "mydomain" and LLMNR disabled, will any single-label lookup request be routed into this interface?

Yes, of course, it **may**. That LLMNR is disabled only blocks local resolution (no other servers on the local (*yes: .local*) network will be asked) but the resolution for that name must find an answer (even if negative) so it **may** (if there is no *NOTFOUND=return* entry, for example) happen that the DNS servers for a matching interface are contacted to resolve `mylocalhost.mylocaldomain` when a resolution for `mylocalhost` was started and there is an entry for `mylocaldomain` in the "search domain". to answer in a **general** sense is almost imposible, too many variables.

#Q2

> If an interface is configured with search domain "mydomain" and LLMNR enabled and a lookup request for "xyz" comes in, will "xyz" through LLMNR and "xyz.mydomain" throuth specified dns server both happen?

No. **if all is correctly configured** a single label name "xyz" should only be resolved by LLMNR, and, even if asked, a DNS server should not try to resolve it. Well, that's theory. But the DNS system **must** resolve `com` (clearly, or the network would fall down as it is now). But there is a simple workaround: ask for `com.`, it has a dot, it is a FQDN. In any case, a DNS server shuld answer with `NOERROR` (with an empty A (or AAAA)) if the server doesn't have enough information about a label and the resolution should continue with the root servers (for `.`). Or with a NXDOMAIN (the best answer to avoid further resolutions) for domains it knows that do not exist.

The only safe way to control this is to have a local DNS server and choose which names to resolve and which not to.

Comment: Thanks very much for your effort! But I am still not quiet clear with your words and ubuntu man docs. I saw there were some conflicts between those statements. I add some questions with more details and hope you could help me.

Comment: @SolaroiZeng No upvote? 

Answer (score 1):

It will be routed to all of them, using both LLMNR and DNS and the first response received will be used.

See this part of the systemd-resolved manpage:

> If lookups are routed to multiple interfaces, the first successful response is returned (thus effectively merging the lookup zones on all matching interfaces). If the lookup failed on all interfaces, the last failing response is returned.

Comment: thanks a lot! Now I confirmed what I was thinking about. By the way, is this means that the rule: 

Lookups for a hostname ending in one of the per-interface domains are exclusively routed to the matching interfaces.

does not apply to single-label case but only multi-label case? I was confused becasue I thought single-label name were implicitly matched by any interfaces configured with "search domain".